# Sorting list based on a single/couple function items

Tags: python-3.x, function, sorting

After the recent FIFA qualifiers, I decided to make a sorted ranking based on a country's qualifier results. This is already posted but I wanted to try to make one.

I made the following function, elements and list:

```
def Scores(Country, wins, draws, losses, goalsfor, goalsagainst):
     points = (wins *3)+ draws
     goaldifference = goalsfor - goalsagainst
     return '{} has {} wins, {} draws, {} losses, {} goal difference, {} points'.format(Country, wins, draws, losses, goaldifference, points)

Honduras = Scores('Honduras',3, 4, 3, 13, 19)
Mexico = Scores('Mexico', 6, 3, 1, 16, 7)
CostaRica = Scores('Costa Rica', 4, 4, 2, 14, 8)
TrinidadAndTobago = Scores('Trinidad And Tobago', 2, 0, 8, 7, 19)
USA = Scores('USA', 3, 3, 4, 17, 13)
Panama = Scores('Panama', 3, 4, 3, 9, 10)

Teams = [Honduras, Mexico, CostaRica, TrinidadAndTobago, USA, Panama]
```

In FIFA, a team is first ranked by points and then by goal difference if there is a tie with points. How can I sort my list of countries based on these parameters, having to reach into a country's results through the function?

Expected results are:
1) Mexico
2) Costa Rica
3) Panama
4) Honduras
5) USA
6) Trinidad And Tobago

Comment: What do you expect your output to be and what are you getting ?

Comment: well not by constructing a function that converts it to a string, but by constructing a class and implement rich comparisons. But this question shows (close to) zero effort to solve the problem.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks for the contribution

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `class` that uses `total_ordering` and a definition of `__eq__` and `__lt__` to be sortable:

```
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering
class Score():
    def __init__(self, country, wins, draws, losses, goals_for, goals_against):
        self.country = country
        self.wins = wins
        self.draws = draws
        self.losses = losses
        self.goals_for = goals_for
        self.goals_against = goals_against

    def _value(self):
        return self.wins * 3 + self.draws, self.goals_for - self.goals_against

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._value() == other._value()

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self._value() < other._value()

Honduras = Score('Honduras',3, 4, 3, 13, 19)
Mexico = Score('Mexico', 6, 3, 1, 16, 7)
CostaRica = Score('Costa Rica', 4, 4, 2, 14, 8)
TrinidadAndTobago = Score('Trinidad And Tobago', 2, 0, 8, 7, 19)
USA = Score('USA', 3, 3, 4, 17, 13)
Panama = Score('Panama', 3, 4, 3, 9, 10)

scores = sorted([Honduras, Mexico, CostaRica, TrinidadAndTobago, USA, Panama], reverse=True)

print([score.country for score in scores])

# Output: ['Mexico', 'Costa Rica', 'Panama', 'Honduras', 'USA', 'Trinidad And Tobago']
```

**UPDATE**

Here's another option, this time with a `namedtuple` and a `key` function in the `sort`. (This keeps the sorting logic outside of the class. Depending on what you're doing, that might be better or worse.)

```
from collections import namedtuple
Score = namedtuple('Score',
    ['country', 'wins', 'draws', 'losses', 'goals_for', 'goals_against'])

Honduras = Score('Honduras',3, 4, 3, 13, 19)
Mexico = Score('Mexico', 6, 3, 1, 16, 7)
CostaRica = Score('Costa Rica', 4, 4, 2, 14, 8)
TrinidadAndTobago = Score('Trinidad And Tobago', 2, 0, 8, 7, 19)
USA = Score('USA', 3, 3, 4, 17, 13)
Panama = Score('Panama', 3, 4, 3, 9, 10)

scores = sorted([Honduras, Mexico, CostaRica, TrinidadAndTobago, USA, Panama],
    key=lambda s: (s.wins * 3 + s.draws, s.goals_for - s.goals_against),
    reverse=True)

print([score.country for score in scores])

# Output: ['Mexico', 'Costa Rica', 'Panama', 'Honduras', 'USA', 'Trinidad And Tobago']
```